# Bigcup not shown

Tags: symbols

For some reason I cannot understand, the symbol `\(\bigcup\)` is not shown in the compiled PDF. There are no error messages. The same is true for `\(\bigsqcup\)`, which I thought I might use as a substitute.

I do not observe other lacunas.

Is this a common problem, and is there a way to resolve it?

As no package is needed for (\bigcup), it seems that the problem may, perhaps, most often arise because two packages are loaded in the wrong order.

The answer, provided by @Jasper Habicht, also resolved the problem that arose with (\Koppa), as explained in the question [A surrogate for \Koppa under Teubner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687141/a-surrogate-for-koppa-under-teubner/687163#687163). As he points out in his answer, the order of the packages teubner and newtxmath is decisive:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\usepackage{newtxmath}% <<<
\usepackage{teubner}

\begin{document}

Hello $\bigcup$ \Koppa\koppa{} $\bigsqcup$ bye

\end{document}
```

Versus

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\usepackage{teubner}% <<<
\usepackage{newtxmath} 

\begin{document}

Hello $\bigcup$ \Koppa\koppa{} $\bigsqcup$ bye

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is hard to tell without a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) ... A first guess would be that the font you use does not contain this glyph. Do you get any warnings?

Comment: @JasperHabicht There are no warnings or error messages. \bigcup is in MnSymbol, fd symbol, and six, and they do not combine well with amsmath etc.

Comment: Then I would suggest that you try to help others help you and tell more about the setup you use: provide a code snippet that generates the problem you experience and shows the document class and packages you use.

Comment: @JasperHabicht \(\bigcup\) should compile with no extra package.

Comment: Well, my guess is that in your document, some other package or font interferes, so this glyph is not printed. Sorry, I cannot tell more without any code provided.

Comment: @JasperHabicht The preamble has mor than 400 lines ...

I will load it in in portions.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I will edit the preamble into the question.

Comment: no, start from  a copy and delete everything you can delete while `$\bigcup$` fails

Comment: The trick is, as always, to stepwise reduce the loaded packages until the problem goes away and this way single out the culprit. I would assume that it is font related. So, you should be able to savely remove all packages that are not font related in a first step.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Meanwhile I glued in the preamble. Hopefully, tomorrow I will be able to localize the problem.

Comment: What @DavidCarlisle is saying is, make a copy of your file.  Delete all the text except the expression using `\bigcup` that doesn't appear.  Compile it, to make sure that the problem isn't something in the text.  Then start removing packages and checking until the symbol "magically" appears.  That will identify what is causing the problem.  And, off-topic: you can cause your code to be formatted here by highlighting it with your mouse, and then clicking on the `{}` icon above the question box.  That makes it much easier to read.

Comment: @barbarabeeton "you can cause your code to be formatted here by highlighting it with your mouse, and then clicking on the {} icon above the question box" Is there a manual for this?

Comment: I don't know of a manual, but also above the question box, to the right, there is a black circle with a question mark in it.  Click that, and a row of text items will appear, with one that says "code".  Clicking on that gives useful information, although not the clue about the `{}` icon.  (I learned about that from another participant.)  One of the hints is that starting each code line with four spaces causes the block to be formatted as code, and that's what the `{}` icon does.  (I sympathize; I don't handle GUIs well.)  These hints are worth reading.

Comment: @barbarabeeton What is a question box?

Comment: At the top of question and answer pages on this site, there is a small box that says "Ask question".  Alternatively, on this page, if you click on the box that says "edit" below the question, an area will open up with the code for the question, headed "Body", and surrounded by a drawn box.  That is what I mean by "question box".  (A corresponding "answer box" is also shown on the page after a question has been asked, with the same set of icons shown above it.)

Comment: You never provided an example but Jasper kindly did, which shows tex does warn of the missing character. The terminal and log shows `Missing character: There is no Ð in font cmex10!`

Comment: I did not vote to close, but I would vote to reopen if you edited the question to have  a reasonable example. Posting 500 lines of unrelated code that no one can run as it references files not provided and has no example of a missing `\bigcup` seems quite a reasonable reason to close as unclear

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I followed your advice and deleted the preamble. Moreover, I wrote the following as an attempt at giving a general diagnosis: "As no package is needed for (\bigcup), it seems that the problem may, perhaps, most often arise because two packages are loaded in the wrong order."

Comment: You should have an example in the question. since Jasper made one for you, all you have to do is copy it. With the question as it is now  no one would have been able to answer it and Jasper's answer appears to come from nowhere.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I believe I followed your advice now.

Comment: Please format code by clicking on the relevant button (with the two `{}`). But more importantly: Why did you paste an existing answer into your question? I think that this is not optimal, since on this site, to my understanding, questions should be formulated as questions and answers as answers. You may add an own answer to the other existing answers if you feel that this would contribute to this thread. Or, if you want to add some information to my answer, you are also welcome to edit it.

Comment: @JasperHabicht OK, so I deleted that from the equation. Your answer is good enough, I think, and it needs no addition from me.

Comment: well not really as you put the answer in the question,  should have made it a question (as you should have phrased it originally) to which the answer post provides an answer. But whatever, someone (not me:-) has opened your post again, so I'd drop this thread and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A MWE showing the problem can be reduced to:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\usepackage{newtxmath} 

\usepackage{teubner}

\begin{document}

Hello $\bigcup$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem seems to be that the `teubner` package redefines several macros. A workaround could be to load the `teubner` package first, but this is untested and other things may break:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\usepackage{teubner}

\usepackage{newtxmath} 

\begin{document}

Hello $\bigcup$

\end{document}
```

[image]

At least, if you load the `teubner` package first and the `newtxmath` later, you should be able to use `\Koppa` and `\koppa` as well as `\bigcup` and `\bigsqcup` it seems:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\usepackage{teubner}

\usepackage{newtxmath} 

\begin{document}

Hello $\bigcup$ \Koppa\koppa{} $\bigsqcup$ bye

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks!  The problem is indeed with Teubner. Unfortunately, it seems that I must miss Archaic Greek Koppa if I delete Teubner - Boisik does not work in my context.

Comment: @Sapiens It should be possible to use all the required glyphs, if you load the `teubner` package before loading the `newtxmath` package, I think. Did you try this?

Comment: Please vote to open the question again.