# A surrogate for \Koppa under Teubner?

Tags: symbols

I have to leave the `teubner` package behind as it creates problems for my Math fonts. (Package `boisik` can also not be used with the other packages I have.)

Unfortunately this means that I will lose access to the letter [Koppa](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Greek_uc_a-koppa.png):

[image]

May someone help recreate Koppa in the presence of the following packages?

(`[T1]{fontenc}`, `[utf8]{inputenc}`, `soul`, `lmodern`, `[greek,english]{babel}`, `[autostyle]{csquotes}`, `amsmath`, `amsthm`, `newtxtext`, `newtxmath`, `parskip`, `adjustbox`, `graphicx`, `enumitem`, `color`, `[dvipsnames]{xcolor}`, `hyperref`, `afterpage`, `epigraph`, `sfdefault`, `rotating`, `ClearSans`, `scalerel`, `marvosym`, `eurosym`, `stmaryrd`, `cancel`, `bm`, `bbm`, `stackengine`, `yfonts`, `tikz`, `[nottoc]{tocbibind}`, `makeidx`, `fancyhdr`)

Comment: This character is shown in the charts for the stix2-otf text font at position 03D8.  This font is available from CTAN.  (But someone else will have to tell you how to access it.)

Comment: Not a math symbol but is available in text mode as `\textQoppa` with your loading of babel greek

Comment: @mbert Thanks! :)

Answer (score 7):

Using `teubner` is not necessary for just obtaining the Qoppa. There is STEP that is Times-compatible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\mathKoppa}{%
  \mathord{\text{\usefont{LGR}{STEP-TLF}{m}{n}\symbol{"15}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\Gamma+\mathKoppa$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! With me there were several errors.