# \(\bigoT\) and \(\bigoL\)?

Tags: symbols

Confer the answer to the following question for

```
\bigoplus, \bigotimes, \bigodot, \bigoslash \& \bigotimes:
```

[\(\bigominus\) and \(\bigoslash\)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687421/bigominus-and-bigoslash)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\let\bigopsize\bigoplus
\def\bigoplus{{\scalerel*{\boldsymbol\oplus}{\bigopsize}}}
\def\bigominus{{\scalerel*{\boldsymbol\ominus}{\bigopsize}}}
\def\bigodot{{\scalerel*{\boldsymbol\odot}{\bigopsize}}}
\def\bigotimes{{\scalerel*{\boldsymbol\otimes}{\bigopsize}}}
\def\bigoslash{{\scalerel*{\boldsymbol\oslash}{\bigopsize}}}



\begin{document}

$\bigoplus \bigominus \bigodot \bigotimes \bigoslash$

$a^\bigoplus$

\end{document}
```

How may one define

```
\bigoT \bigoL,
```

which are like `\bigoplus`, `\bigotimes`, `\bigodot`, `\bigoslash` and `\bigotimes`, but with the central symbol replaced by a centered T, and L?

Comment: Questions on TeX.se should be self-sustained. It would be nice if you could edit your post to include a MWE so people don't have to follow a link in order to try to understand your question.

Comment: The linked question is about as long as the current question.  If you move the context here instead, this question will be much easier to understand.  And if you provide the context that you are using asmsymb, you might get an answer you can use.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Yes (but make sure you have the formatting you want).  But the other question pointed you to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/623875/107497, which shows how to make anything inside a `\bigo`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Please re-read this comment which explained to you how to insert code blocks: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687134/bigcup-not-shown#comment1704905_687134

Comment: Related question: [How to create my own math operator with limits? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-create-my-own-math-operator-with-limits) and [tikz pgf - Plus-minus sign in a circle? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117117/plus-minus-sign-in-a-circle)

Comment: @Teepeemm No, I don't see an algorithm I can use.

Answer (score -2):

I solved my problems by using the circledsteps-package. It gives access to adequate circlings of numbers, letters and short strings.

(\Circled{T}, \Circled{L}) give a circle around a T, and a circle around an L.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your solution, by EDITing your answer to add the code? Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/251461)

Comment: @MS-SPO I edited in the solution now.

Comment: Thank you ... but can't you please show it as code, we can copy and compile? Snippets don't help that much ...